# Change directory during a build job on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I am building a gradle project and the source code is in git. After checking our repo to jenkins' workspace, how do i have jenkins go to a sub-directory and do the build?

I tried adding shell commands but cd will not work as it executes script on a separate shell.

Answer (score 7):

If you are building a gradle project, perhaps you should use the "**Invoke gradle script**" step rather than a shell script?

As part of the gradle build script, it has an option to specify the "**Root Build script**", which will let allow you to specify a subdirectory if you wish.

See the [Gradle plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin) for more information.

Comment: Thank you! Solved my issue.

Comment: Thanks. This resolved my issue as well.